# Property 'strDrink' does not exist on type 'string' (TypeScript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-state

On my React/TypeScript project I am trying to get keys of object "recipe" after setCurrentRecipe(cocktail) like that:

```
         const [recipe, setCurrentRecipe] = useState("");
         JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).map(cocktail: any) => {
         return (
         <Button onClick={() => {
            setCurrentRecipe(cocktail)
         }}></Button>
         )}
```

(cocktail is big object)

And App component:

`<DrawerHeader>recipe of {recipe.strDrink}</DrawerHeader>`

recipe.strDrink is string. I got: "Property 'strDrink' does not exist on type 'string'"

What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const [recipe, setCurrentRecipe] = useState("")` sets the initial value for `recipe` to an empty string. As the error message says, there is no such property as `strDrink` on an empty string. Try a different initial value: `const [recipe, setRecipe] = useState({strDrink: ""})`